# Bolding part of paragraph with vba in ms word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having trouble bolding part of a paragraph in `MS WORD`.
I am building a document paragraph by paragraph. In only one of those I want to bold only one number. The number may occur more than once in the document but should be bolded only once, in this specific paragraph.

Example:

My first paragraph.

My second paragraph.

My number is **123**.

I access paragraphs with the following code:

```
Dim paragraphN As Integer
paragraphN = 3
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Paragraphs(paragraphN).Range
```

I don`t know how to specify only a part of this specific paragraph.
I tried:

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Paragraphs(paragraphN).Range(Start:=14, End:=17).Font.Bold = True

ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Paragraphs(paragraphN).Range.Characters(Start:=14, End:=17).Font.Bold = True

ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Paragraphs(paragraphN).Characters(Start:=14, End:=17).Range.Font.Bold = True

ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Paragraphs(paragraphN).Characters.Range(Start:=14, End:=17).Font.Bold = True

ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Paragraphs(paragraphN).Range(14,17).Font.Bold = True
```

All failed. The problem seems pretty straightforward but I am out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using a slightly different method:

```
   ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters(5).Start, _
   ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters(10).End).Font.Bold = True
```

You can adjust the paragraph numbers and character numbers with your variables.

Comment: So this implies that `Range` object somehow differs depending on where it was used, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because I couldn't do a Range(x, y) without an error.  This worked for me however...  `doc.Paragraphs(paragraphIndex).Range.Sentences(1).Font.Bold = True`

Comment: Aside from the fact that what works for you wouldn't have worked for the OP, you need to be aware that VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following: *Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.* For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.

Comment: I came Googling with the same question and came to this page.  As you point out, my answer will have no value to some people with the same question.  But the accepted answer had no value to me.  The goal of SO is not to help the one individual that had a question, but to also help the thousands of people that will have the same question later.